# Manually generate id of document inserted into Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

I want to get the id of a created document without having to make a separate query to get the document after it is created. I'm thinking I'll need to manually create the id of the document before creating it. Is there a way to do this? I'm using the `mongoose` driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create a new mongoose model instance, its `_id` value is already set to what it will be when saved.  For example:

```
var user = new User();
// user._id is already set.
...
user.save();
```